Using Manticore search with llamaindex
I working on a ChatBot project using llamaindex. In there, I need to combine MySQL database which is indexed using Manticore search and PDF documents as embeddings. I'm following example of https://docs.llamaindex.ai/en/stable/examples/query_engine/SQLJoinQueryEngine/. My problem is I can not use NLSQLTableQueryEngine since Manticore search queries are slightly different from MySQL select statements. What is the best way to achieve this?
I'm OK with either customizing NLSQLTableQueryEngine to work with Manticore search or creating custom modules.
